# Http request for GET method having querystrings

Tags: node.js

I made an http GET request via **node.js** through following code

```
http.get({host:'google.com'},
        function(res){});
```

But how to make GET requests having querystrings,
for eg: http://myhost/path?query1="val1"&query2="val2"
???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just add the path like this:

```
var options = {
  host: 'myhost',
  port: 80,
  path: '/path?query1=val1&query2=val2'
};

http.get(options, function(res) {
  console.log("Got response: " + res.statusCode);
}).on('error', function(e) {
  console.log("Got error: " + e.message);
});
```